# Provisioning failed. OS Provisioning for VM 'VM Name' did not finish in the allotted time

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I'm new to Azure. I'm trying to create resources in Azure using powershell.

My requirement is to create an image from a VM. I have followed to ways to do it :

**Process 1:   Do it manually**
Generalize the VM : Login to VM -> Open command prompt -> cd %windir%\system32\sysprep --> run sysprep.exe --> Check generalize button--> Shutdown.

Create snapshot : Go to Azure portal-> Go to the VM which is generalized --> Click on Capture button --> Give image name and mention resource group and click on Create.

This will create an Image.

**Process 2: Do it with powershell**

```
   # create session of the VM

    $UserName = "$IPAddress\$adminUsername"
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $adminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    $psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)
    $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $IPAddress -Credential $psCred

    # Run SysPrep for generalizing the VM

    $sysprep = 'C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe'
    $arg = '/generalize /oobe /shutdown /quiet'
    Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {param($sysprep,$arg)Start-Process -FilePath $sysprep -ArgumentList $arg} -ArgumentList $sysprep,$arg

    #Stop the VM

    Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $virtualMachineName -Force


    # Generalize the VM

    Set-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $virtualMachineName -Generalized

    # Create the Image

    $vm = Get-AzureRmVM -Name $virtualMachineName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
    $image = New-AzureRmImageConfig -Location $location -SourceVirtualMachineId $vm.ID
    New-AzureRmImage -Image $image -ImageName $ImageName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
```

Both the processes will create a Image.  But the problem I'm facing here is when I spin VM from the image created from Process 1 , it is created successfully without any issue.
But when I spin VM from image created from Process2 , it is getting created but with below error message :

> Provisioning failed. OS Provisioning for VM 'VM Name' did not finish
>   in the allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected
>   running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to
>   be used as a VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage).

Can anyone tell me what it is I'm doing wrong with powershell script, that I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time seems to be the issue.

Sysprep normally takes 10 - 15 minutes, you have no sleep time. You are shutting down VM as soon as the sysprep script is sent, no time to actually sysprep system.

You can either put a sleep time or a loop to check when VM is in a `Stopped` state.

Comment: are you suggesting me to put a sleep time after this line ?  :  Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {param($sysprep,$arg)Start-Process -FilePath $sysprep -ArgumentList $arg} -ArgumentList $sysprep,$arg

Comment: About 20 minutes sleep will be the duct tape fix, yes. Really what you want is to have something to check on VM state and to only stop VM when it's in a Stopped state that way you know sysprep is done.

Comment: Can you tell me, if there is any command in powershell to determine if sysprep is done or if the VM is in stopped state?

Comment: Created a script to do exactly what you are trying to do a few years back, i guess i deleted it because used it only twice.  But the code should look like code on linked snippet https://codepad.co/snippet/azure-vm-status-check-loop

Comment: How do we get back to the generalized VM? After the capturing process finished, I cannot turn on the VM. It says `Failed to start virtual machine 'VM-Name'. Error: Operation 'Start VM' is not allowed on VM 'VM-Name' since the VM is generalized.`

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few docs on papering and creating VMs from images in Azure. As the error suggests, you likely missed a step.

If you are uploading a VHD from on prem to use in Azure, start with these docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed

If the VM you are capturing an image of is already in Azure and working, then start with these

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-generalized-managed?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json

The last link shows you how to create the VM from that image via the portal or a simple PS command

```
New-AzVm `
    -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
    -Name "myVMfromImage" `
    -ImageName "myImage" `
    -Location "East US" `
    -VirtualNetworkName "myImageVnet" `
    -SubnetName "myImageSubnet" `
    -SecurityGroupName "myImageNSG" `
    -PublicIpAddressName "myImagePIP" `
    -OpenPorts 3389
```